# c# HttpWebRequest IOException

Tags: c#

I am using the following function to navigate to URL addresses in my c# winform code.

I think, the code is fine but when it tries to make connection to the URL address, it fails and throws a *IOException Error*:

My Question is:

**How can I add a check in the code to make sure that connection to URL is successfully made and if it is not, than it will re-try until it makes a successful connection?**

```
public String WebRequestNavigate(string url)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            if (url != "")
            {
                HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                myReq.KeepAlive = false;
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
                    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

                    String test = "";
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {

                        **count = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);**

                        if (count != 0)
                        {
                            test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                            sb.Append(test);
                        }
                    }
                    while (count > 0);
                    stream.Close();
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {

                }


            }


            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Thanks friends for all of your answers. They are all correct. However, I finally found my error and corrected it.

The problem is I was trying to catch WebException , however, the error I was getting IOException.

I changed WebException as IOException and corrected my code as following:

```
catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);                       
                       myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                       myReq.KeepAlive = false;
                    }
```

I used your suggestion for Thread.Sleep in order to make my code wait before attempting a new URL connection. This solved my problem %100.

Sorry for taking your time but you helped me in a great way and provided insight. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask what url you are trying to connect to?

Comment: url addresses vary. Not a single url address if you meant that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing similar but simpler:

```
Stream stream = null;

while (stream == null)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
        stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        // plus idea: die after a few try?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (but not necessarily the "best") way to do this, would be to wrap it in a while loop, and create a booleans variable that confirms whether or not the connection succeeeded. If it never succeeds, then `ConnectionSucceeded` will never get set to `true`.

```
public String WebRequestNavigate(string url)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            if (url != "")
            {
                bool ConnectionSucceeded;
                while (!ConnectionSucceeded) {
                    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    myReq.KeepAlive = false;
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
                        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

                        String test = "";
                        int count = 0;
                        do
                        {

                            count = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                            if (count != 0)
                            {
                                test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                                sb.Append(test);
                            }
                        }
                        while (count > 0);
                        stream.Close();
                        ConnectionSucceeded = true;
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }


            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make use of WebClient in a manner similar to this:

```
string result = "";
bool success = false;
int remainingAttempts = 5;

while(success == false && remainingAttempts > 0) {

    remainingAttempts--;

    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        result = client.DownloadString(url);
        success = true;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
    }

    if(success == false) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx for reference.

Comment: The issue with `WebClient` is that it doesn't provide the same functionality as `HttpWebRequest`. They aren't really interchangeable, depending on what the OP is attempting to achieve.

Comment: I agree that they are not interchangeable, and this is certainly worth mentioning.  However, based on his code sample it appears he wants a string representation of the contents found at the url.